# Передача vector из С++\CLI в C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Есть такой метод:

```
void App::TestFilesOpen( const std::vector<std::wstring> & fileVector)
{
  int size = fileVector.size();
  array<System::String ^> ^ fileArray = gcnew array<System::String ^>( size );
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    fileArray[i] = gcnew System::String( fileVector[i].c_str() );
  window_->SendFilePathsToRecorder( fileArray );
}
```

Какой типа параметра должен быть в методе SendFilePathsToRecorder на С#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам нужен

```
string[]
```

---

Символ `^` в C++/CLI означает ссылку, ссылочные типы передаются именно так — по ссылке. То есть при трансляции из C++/CLI в C# ссылочные типы должны передаваться с `^`, и на стороне C# эту крышку записывать не надо. Точно так же, массив содержит не сами элементы ссылочного типа, а ссылки на них, что записывается как `System::String^`.

Ну и `array<...>` — это просто .NET-массив, кодируется при помощи `[]` в C#.